Plumbing through the shared space - townhouse
I need to move the plumbing from the floor to the wall, however that would mean having plumbing inside the shared wall space with the neighbour( it’s a townhouse). Is this allowed?
If yes I can keep it close to the drywall inside my unit and have some insulation/ blocker behind it.
If not what are my other options?

Depends. Country and local laws, HOA, building project, neighbour agreement, etc...

If done DIY and something bad happens, you will be responsible for any flooding of the neighbours, most likely without any help/money from insurance.

Are we talking just the copper supply lines?

@huesmann- Yes just the copper lines coming in from the floor. Since the drain inlet is already in that space I wanted to check if the supply pipes could also?

@crip659- plan to have a professional come in .. need to change the copper lines to pex. I can keep it on the floor itself and just shift it closer to my drywall.. if going behind the wall is risky/a violation.

@k_z: I’m in GA if that helps
